# AngularJS controller "as" operator

Tags: angularjs, controller

I have this view in AngularJS:

```
<form ng-submit="addCust.submit();"  ng-controller="AddCustomerCtrl as addCust">
<div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="addCust.cName" required />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="addCust.cCity" required />
</div>
<div>
    <button type="submit">Add Customer</button>
</div>
```

And my controller is:

```
helloWorldControllers.controller('AddCustomerCtrl',['$scope','$location',
function AddCustomerCtrl($scope, $location){
    $scope.submit = function(){
        $location.path('/addedCustomer/' + $scope.cName + "/" + $scope.cCity);
    };
}
]);
```

But the "as" operator doesn't work in my netbeans.

My goal is to attach multiple controllers to one element, so I don't want to change the name of controller in itself, but as needed in the view where I want to attach controller to the element.
Can anyone please help me where it is wrong?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your controller as:

```
helloWorldControllers.controller('AddCustomerCtrl',['$location', function AddCustomerCtrl($location){ 
  var addCust = this;
  addCust.submit = function(){ $location.path('/addedCustomer/' + addCust.cName + "/" + addCust.cCity); }; } ]);
```

Comment: thanks, your answer is right, but my goal is to attach multiple controllers to one element, so I don't want to change the name of controller in itself, but as needed in the view where I want to attach controller to the element.